# ¿Cómo puedo indentar con tab un div ContentEditable?

Tags: javascript

Hasta hace poco usaba un textarea como un pequeño "editor de código" que hay en la aplicación que estoy haciendo en JS, y como editor de código que es, necesita permitir usar el `<tab>` para indentar. Con el textarea, usaba este código:

```
codeBox.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==9 || e.which==9){
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = this.selectionStart;
        this.value = this.value.substring(0,this.selectionStart) + "    " + this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd);
        this.selectionEnd = s + 4; 
    }
```

Sí, se usan 4 espacios en vez de tabs.

El problema es que he decidido cambiar el textarea por un div con *ContentEditable* (para cosas estilísticas del texto y cosas así), pero el código anterior ya no funciona, y la razón es que `selectionStart`y `selectionEnd` no son propiedades más que de inputs y textarea.

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer esto para divs?

Answer (score 1):

No hay solución elegante, pero este truco te puede servir. Recuerda que si no añades `white-space:pre-wrap;` a los CSS del editor, no funciona.

```js
$(document).on('keydown','#editor', function(e){
  //detect 'tab' key
  if(e.keyCode == 9){
    //add tab
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '&#009');
    //prevent focusing on next element
    e.preventDefault()   
  }
});
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  white-space:pre-wrap
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

Respuesta obtenida de la versión [en inglés de tu pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237497/how-to-make-the-tab-key-insert-a-tab-character-in-a-contenteditable-div)

Comment: Muchas gracias, modificándolo un poco he logrado hacer casi lo que necesito. Pero me surge un problema para mejorar la indentación, y es que necesito obtener la posición y la línea en la que se encuentra el puntero dentro del div. ¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano.